# ThreadLocal context lost with CompletableFuture in Java

Tags: java, datasource, completable-future, thread-local

I have a class, DatabaseContextHolder, that manages the data source based on the user's API key using ThreadLocal.

```
public final class DatabaseContextHolder {

    private static final ThreadLocal<Stack<DataSourceType>> ctx = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public static void setCtx(DataSourceType dataSourceType) {
        getCtx().push(dataSourceType);
    }

    public static void restoreCtx() {
        final Stack<DataSourceType> ctx = getCtx();
        if (!ctx.isEmpty()) {
            ctx.pop();
        }
    }

    public static Optional<DataSourceType> peekDataSource() {
        final Stack<DataSourceType> ctx = getCtx();

        if (ctx.isEmpty()) {
            return Optional.empty();
        }

        return Optional.of(ctx.peek());
    }

    private static Stack<DataSourceType> getCtx() {
        if (ctx.get() == null) {
            ctx.set(new Stack<>());
        }

        return ctx.get();
    }
}
```

This works fine without multi-threading. However, when I use CompletableFuture, the ctx field is always empty inside the asynchronous tasks.
Example of methods with CompletableFuture:

```
private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

public ResponseEntity<Map<String, List<ReportGroupScheduleExecutionBean>>> getScheduleExecutionByGroup(@RequestParam(value = "accountId") int accountId,
                                                                                                           @RequestParam("dateFrom") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime dateFrom,
                                                                                                           @RequestParam("dateTo") @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime dateTo,
                                                                                                           @RequestParam(name = "groupIds") Set<Integer> groupIds,
                                                                                                           @AuthenticationPrincipal UserBean userBean) throws NoDataException {
        ZoneId userTimeZone = ZoneId.of(userBean.getUserTimeZone());
        DateTimeFormatter zoneTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(ModelsConstants.PATTERN_TIME_ONLY_MINUTES).withZone(userTimeZone);
        AccountEntity account = accountService.findById(accountId).orElseThrow(() -> new NoDataException("Account not exist"));
        List<CompletableFuture<List<ReportGroupScheduleExecutionBean>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
        groupIds.forEach(id -> {
            CompletableFuture<List<ReportGroupScheduleExecutionBean>> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                    () -> {
                        try {
                            return reportService.getRouteScheduleExecutionReportByGroup(new ReportInfoBean(
                                    dateFrom, dateTo, account, userBean.getUserTimeZone(), zoneTimeFormatter), id);
                        } catch (NoDataException e) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(e);
                        }
                    }, executorService);
            futures.add(future);
        });
        CompletableFuture<Void> allFutures = CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]));
        CompletableFuture<List<ReportGroupScheduleExecutionBean>> futuresAll = allFutures.thenApply
                (v -> futures.stream()
                        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                        .flatMap(List::stream)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
                );
        try {
            return new ResponseEntity<>(futuresAll.get().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ReportGroupScheduleExecutionBean::getAccountName)), HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

What I've Tried:

- mark all methods as synchronized
- tried different executors for CompletableFuture

How can I ensure that the ThreadLocal context is propagated correctly to threads spawned by CompletableFuture?

Comment: Making ThreadLocals work correctly this way is very difficult and best avoided.

Comment: This could be a use case for `ScopedValue` in the future, however, since the posted code doesn’t interact with `DatabaseContextHolder` at all, there is nothing that could be changed in this code to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I ensure that the ThreadLocal context is propagated correctly to threads spawned by CompletableFuture?

You seem to have altogether the wrong idea about `ThreadLocal`.  The whole point is that a given `ThreadLocal` object holds a different, independent value for each thread.  Whatever value one thread `set()`s on it, *that thread alone* can `get()` back from it.  The objective is to *avoid* sharing data between threads.

Thus ...

> when I use CompletableFuture, the ctx field is always empty inside the asynchronous tasks

Yes! The asynchronous tasks run in different threads from the one in which you set a value in the `ThreadLocal`, so they are not supposed to see that value in the `ThreadLocal`.  Nor a copy of it or any such thing, either.  They get either its initial value or whatever value they last set themselves.

You can partially break that by causing your `ThreadLocal` instance to provide the same object as its initial value to all threads, but that is inappropriate under most circumstances.  If you want a shared object then dispense with the `ThreadLocal` and set up such an object directly.  `ThreadLocal` does not do anything useful for you in that case.  In particular, it does not provide any kind of synchronization for a shared object exposed as its initial value to multiple threads.

---

It seems unlikely that you want thread-specific `Stack`s that are not also task-specific, but if you did want that then you could avoid each thread having to `set()` its own by configuring a `ThreadLocal` with an initial value supplier, via [`withInitial()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en%2Fjava%2Fjavase%2F21%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java.base/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html#withInitial(java.util.function.Supplier)):

```
    private static final ThreadLocal<Stack<DataSourceType>> ctx =
            ThreadLocal.withInitial(Stack::new);
```

Again, I don't think that's what you actually want, but I include it for completeness.